# Adding values ​to the correct subject with LINQ C# Code

Tags: c#, linq

I need someone's help because I've been here for a while with this problem and can't figure it out. Would be super cool if you could help me!

What the list looks like now (1 object):

datatype:

- Id1 = string
- Id2 = string
- Value = string

  [image: enter code here]

**The reason value is a String is because it is a result of a percentage of a previous method

I would like to add the values ​​of the 2 unique id in the new table.
So with an foreach loop from the list above i want as result as below:

[image]

If anyone could help me that would be great! thanks in advance!!!

Comment: add example code: what does your table look like? 2d array of strings? 1d array of objects(id1, id2, value).

Comment: "The reason value is a String is because it is a result of a percentage of a previous method" Fix your previous method first...

Comment: @Blechdose Thanks for your comment! Sorry my example was not very clear.
It is 1 object.

Id 1 = SubjectId
Id 2 = TypeId
Value = is the result of a percentage calculation

Comment: add it as a code example in your question. add the class. the more example code you present the better people can understand your problem and find a propriate solution. example code = real code. Do not only describing the code with text. maybe even add code you tried out but which did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem by grouping objects by Id1 and Id2. By the way, you sould share the test model and initialize the collection on problem definition next time

```
    internal class TestModel
    {
        public TestModel(string id1, string id2, string value)
        {
            Id1 = id1;
            Id2 = id2;
            Value = value;
        }
        public string Id1 { get; set; }
        public string Id2 { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    private void ProcessTest()
    {
        TestModel[] items = new TestModel[]
        {
            new TestModel("1","1","20.2"),
            new TestModel("1","2","18.5"),
            new TestModel("1","2","11.5"),
            new TestModel("2","1","20"),
            new TestModel("2","1","20"),
            new TestModel("2","2","50"),
            new TestModel("2","2","40"),
        };
        var result = items.GroupBy(w => new { w.Id1, w.Id2 })//group by Id1 and Id2
                .Select(w => new TestModel(w.Key.Id1, w.Key.Id2, 
                    w.Sum(q => Convert.ToDecimal(q.Value)).ToString()))//calculate the sum of group values
                .ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Id1", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Id2", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(decimal));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1, 20.2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2, 18.5 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2, 11.5 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 1, 20 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 1, 20 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 2, 50 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 2, 40 });

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => new { id1 = x.Field<int>("Id1"), id2 = x.Field<int>("Id2") })
                .ToList();

            DataTable results = dt.Clone();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                results.Rows.Add(new object[] { group.Key.id1, group.Key.id2, group.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("Value"))});
            }


        }
    }
}
```